# How to use the Input Dialog to execute SQL queries

Tags: sql, matlab, user-input

Is it possible to use the `inputdlg`function to execute an SQL query such as below :

```
    pdbSearchQuery = input('Enter your PDB Code: ', 's');
    curs = fetch(exec(conn, ['SELECT * FROM cath_2_wo_dup WHERE pdbcode = ' '''' pdbSearchQuery '''']));
    pdbSearchResults = curs.Data
```

I manage to do this by default, using the Command Window to search for columns in a database, but i would like to create a dialog box where users can type in a value to search the database, using the variables i have stated above.

It would look like this at the end:

[image: Search bar to search for n column from the database table]

When they click 'OK', it would lead that button to execute another script where it will create the tables and figures for them.

Is this possible to do in `inputdlg` or is there another function that does this similar method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely possible and will give you a lot of freedom in your code.  For example, modified from the `inputdlg` help:

```
prompt = {'Enter table name:','Enter query field:'};
dlg_title = 'Input for query';
num_lines = 1;
def = {'mytable','thatProperty'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);
curs = fetch(exec(conn, ['SELECT * FROM ' char(answer{1}) ' WHERE ' char(answer{1}) '= ' '''' pdbSearchQuery '''']));
```

Should work well.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed a few names and variables around and i manage to retrieve columns from the database. However, when i ran this code as a script and type in a value in the input field and hit 'OK', MATLAB crashes. Could it be that it can't handle the number of scripts i am executing after the dialog window? I tried not executing anything, it still crashes. Please advise.

Comment: @Jeiman, I think it's likely the `exec` or `fetch` crashing, do you have multiple database connections at once?  Also, when you say "not executing anything", you mean not executing any m-script after the call to the dialog box?

Comment: My apologies, i called out my other scripts too early before another script could take place. It's fixed now and working properly. Thank you very much for the explanation and solution.